# Problema ao rodar "cordova run" - A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, npm, gradle, android-sdk

É a primeira vez que instalo o cordova e estou tendo o seguinte problema ao tentar compilar qualquer projeto:

```
C:\ProjetosCordova\lsls>cordova run --debug
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\tools
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary 
configuration failure takes precedence.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
    at 
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at 
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:645)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:608)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.call(BasePlugin.java:605)
    at 
com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
    at 
com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:120)
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.353 secs

    at 
com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$1(BasePlugin.java:603)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\ProjetosCordova\lsls\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' 
line: 64

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 
19.1.0 or higher.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
debug option to get more log output.
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Estou tentando rodar:
 `* Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --
    debug option to get more log output.`
Mas estou tendo o mesmo erro.

Eu tentei rodar `android list sdk --all`, e tive essa mensagem:

```
C:\Users\octav>android list sdk --all
**************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat
**************************************************************************

"android" SDK commands can be translated to sdkmanager commands on a best-effort 
basis.
(This prompt can be suppressed with the --use-sdk-wrapper commend-line argument
or by setting the USE_SDK_WRAPPER environment variable)
Continue? [y/N]:
```

Seguindo com  "y":

```
build-tools;19.1.0
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 19.1
Version:            19.1.0
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\19.1.0

build-tools;20.0.0
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 20
Version:            20.0.0
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\20.0.0

build-tools;21.1.2
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 21.1.2
Version:            21.1.2
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\21.1.2

build-tools;22.0.1
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 22.0.1
Version:            22.0.1
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\22.0.1

build-tools;23.0.1
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1
Version:            23.0.1
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\23.0.1

build-tools;23.0.2
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.2
Version:            23.0.2
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\23.0.2

build-tools;23.0.3
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.3
Version:            23.0.3
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\23.0.3

build-tools;24.0.0
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 24
Version:            24.0.0
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\24.0.0

build-tools;24.0.1
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.1
Version:            24.0.1
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\24.0.1

build-tools;24.0.2
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.2
Version:            24.0.2
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\24.0.2

build-tools;24.0.3
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 24.0.3
Version:            24.0.3
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\24.0.3

build-tools;25.0.0
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 25
Version:            25.0.0
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\25.0.0

build-tools;25.0.1
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.1
Version:            25.0.1
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\25.0.1

build-tools;25.0.2
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.2
Version:            25.0.2
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\25.0.2

build-tools;25.0.3
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 25.0.3
Version:            25.0.3
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\25.0.3

build-tools;26.0.0
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 26
Version:            26.0.0
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\26.0.0

build-tools;26.0.1
Description:        Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.1
Version:            26.0.1
Installed Location: C:\Android\build-tools\26.0.1
```

Quando eu rodo `echo %ANDROID_HOME%`:

```
C:\Users\octav>echo %ANDROID_HOME%
C:\Android\tools
```

E o `echo %JAVA_HOME%`:

```
C:\Users\octav>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

Parte do meu path:

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ruype.png)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, está faltando as ferramentas do SDK do Android. Por favor, tente o seguinte:

```
android list sdk --all
android update sdk -u -a -t <package no.>
```

Pacotes 19, 20, 21

Ou pode baixar támbem pelo Android Studio

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o resultado desse comando "android list sdk --all". No caso eu instalei todas essas versões a partir da 19 pelo próprio android studio

Comment: Felipe, eu reinstalei o android studio e reconfigurei meu Path, percebi que havia cometido alguns erros ao selecionar a pasta do meu android sdk ao instala-lo. Só que agora estou tendo a seguinte mensagem ao tentar roda  este comando "cordova run android":  
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\octav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
    Error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined